# Using a class within an enhanced for-loop

Tags: java

I've written a class that implements Collection and Iterable, and I am attempting to run it through an enhanced for-loop now. You can find it here: [LinkedQueue](http://pastie.org/8415154)

The point of the class is to be able to go through the collection using LinkedQueue.getNext(), which works fine. However I also want to be able to iterate over the values once using a for loop. The current code:

```
LinkedQueue<String> queue = new LinkedQueue();
queue.add("Test one");
queue.add("Test two");
queue.add("Test three");
System.out.println("queue.size = " + queue.size());
System.out.println("contents:");
for (String s : queue) {
    System.out.print("Test: ");
    System.out.println(s);
}
System.out.println("contents (x9):");
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    System.out.println(queue.getNext());
}
```

Prints out this:

```
queue.size = 3
contents:
contents (x9):
Test one
Test two
Test three
...etc...
```

So it seems that the for loop isn't printing properly. I don't think it's an issue of size, since the queue has a size of 3 before starting. So now my problem is most likely "what is wrong with the iterable methods", which are `hasNext()`, `next()`, and `remove()` (which is unsupported in this queue). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: I've added debug statements already, and couldn't find anything. The size is correct, and the values are within the queue.

Comment: Code should be included in the question, not simply linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is failing because when you (implicitly) call `iterator()`, your `itr` variable still refers to just the "null value" node. You only set it to any other value in the `next()` method, which isn't called until later.

However, there's a more serious design problem. Fundamentally, a collection should pretty much never implement `iterator()` itself. You should normally be able to iterate over an collection multiple times - potentially with multiple iterators at the same time, which should all be independent. Iterating over the collection shouldn't change it.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but an `iterator()` implementation should nearly always create a *new* object with some mutable state, which *refers* to the original collection but doesn't alter it.

Comment: So then create a class that would implement iterator itself, and pass the value of my current Queue onto the iterator?

Comment: @Rogue The usual pattern is to implement Iterator in an inner class of some kind.

Comment: @DonalFellows Well yes, it would be an inner class in this case, but as long as that all works then that's good for me. I wasn't 100% if enhanced for-loops called .iterator() or used the object itself

Comment: @Rogue http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html says “Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the "`foreach`" statement.” (Collection is derived from Iterable, BTW.)

Comment: And the reason to do it that way is that it lets you have two iterations over the same collection at once. There's all sorts of reasons to want to be able to support that (even leaving aside doing it from multiple threads).

Comment: @DonalFellows and Jon thanks a bunch, the inner class worked fine, and it worked concurrently as well.